# Primeng password template suggestions not coming up

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

The demo provided at https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-password-demo doesnt work properly as shown in the documentation demo at https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/password for template password, the suggestion are not coming up in the stackblitz demo.

[Documentation demo snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpQhE.png)

[Stackblitz demo snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWHhk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for `p-password` component doesn't show `pTemplate` is reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/10355).

By **upgrading the `primeng` to the latest version (v12.0.1)** will be able to tackle this issue.

**Pre-requisites:**

> Angular App with version 12

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nj6aex?file=angular.json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your css:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-password input {
    width: 15rem;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-password-panel .p-password-meter .p-password-strength.weak {
  background: #D32F2F;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-password-panel .p-password-meter .p-password-strength.medium {
    background: #FBC02D;
}

:host ::ng-deep .p-password-panel .p-password-meter .p-password-strength.strong {
    background: #689F38;
}
```